# Sudoku Solver Program - no change in output

Tags: c++, recursion, backtracking, recursive-backtracking

`solveSudoku` function is called from `main()` function.

I have written the following function for solving sudoku :

```
bool isFull(vector<vector<char>>& board){
        for(int i = 0 ; i < board.size(); i++){
            for(int j = 0 ; j < board[0].size(); j++){
                if(board[i][j] == '.') return false;
            }
        }  
        return true;
    }
    
    vector<int> poss(vector<vector<char>>& board, int x, int y){
        vector<int> ans;
        set<int> s;
        
        //check across columns
        for(int j = 0 ; j < board[0].size(); j++){
            if(board[x][j]!='.')  s.insert(board[x][j] -'0');
        }
        
        //check acroos rows
        for(int i = 0 ; i < board.size(); i++){
            if(board[i][y]!='.')   s.insert(board[i][y] - '0');
        }
        
        //check in square
        int r, c;
        if(x>=0 && x<=2) r = 0;
        if(x>=3 && x<=5) r = 3;
        if(x>=6 && x<=8) r = 6;
        
        if(y>=0 && y<=2) c = 0;
        if(y>=3 && y<=5) c = 3;
        if(y>=6 && y<=8) c = 6;
        
        for(int i = r; i <= r + 2; i++){
            for(int j = c; j <= c + 2; j++){
                if(board[i][j]!='.') s.insert(board[i][j]-'0');
            }
        }
        
        for(int n = 1; n <=9 ; n++){
            if(s.find(n) == s.end()){
                ans.push_back(n);
            }
        }
        
        
        return ans;
    }
    
    vector<int> Fempty(vector<vector<char>>& board){
        vector<int> ans;
        
        for(int i = 0; i < board.size(); i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < board[0].size(); j++){
                if(board[i][j] == '.'){
                    ans.push_back(i);
                    ans.push_back(j);
                    return ans;
                }
            }
        }
        
        return ans;
    }
    
    void solveSudoku(vector<vector<char>>& board) {
        
        if(isFull(board))  return;
        
        //not full
        //Fempty returns first empty cell coordinate
        vector<int> empty = Fempty(board);
        int xe = empty[0], ye = empty[1];
        
        //poss returns the vector of possible values
        vector<int> pos = poss(board, xe, ye);
        
        if(!pos.empty()){
        for(int i = 0; i < pos.size(); i++){
            board[xe][ye] = pos[i] + '0';
            solveSudoku(board);
        }}
        board[xe][ye] = '.';
        
        return;
        
        
    }
```

Input sudoku is given as argument when `solveSudoku` is called in the `main()` function. It consists of characters from `1` to `9` and `.` which represents empty character. `solveSudoku` function's job is to fill all the elements in sudoku correctly(change values in `board` in place).

When I run this program my output shows no change.

If I comment out `board[xe][ye] = '.'`, my output shows some changes but it remains same after a cell runs out of possible values.

Edit : It is known that `board` has a solution.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: `When I run this program my output shows no change.` where do you output ? if in *main* of course you see no change because by definition at the end *solveSudoku* returns *board* unchanged. You must output the board when `if(isFull(board))`before to  `return` rather than to just `return;`. Of course you need `board[xe][ye] = '.';`

Comment: Print the board when `isFull` returns true.

Comment: Recommendation: Add `main`. Bonus points alter `main` it you feeds in a canned set of inputs that exposes the behaviour you want dealt with.

Comment: @bruno I  have printed `board` after calling `solveSudoku`. Why will `board` remain unchanged at end of `SolveSudoku`? It is passed by reference. `isFull(board)` returns `true` only when I have no empty cells. If all cells all filled, I return `solveSudoku` and output its values.

Comment: However I just see `board[xe][ye] = '.';` must be moved inside `if(!pos.empty()){`after the `for` rather than after the `if`

Comment: Your `solveSudoku` function needs to stop when it finds a solution. Your base case is when the board is already full (solved). Then keep setting the first empty cell to a different value and calling `solveSudoku` until it returns `true` (solved) or you're out of values (not possible in current configuration).

Comment: @Kevin it is possible if the input is a board with no solutions.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. In which case `solveSudoku` will try all possible combinations but still return `false`, and leave the board in the original state.

Comment: @Kevin It is known that board has a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagine board contains a full sodoku, with only one cell blank ('.')
SolveSudoku will identify the cell, pos would have a single value, the for loop will do only one step (and do some weird thing to board !)
Then in the loop SolveSudoku is called recursively, as the board is full now, this recursive call will return at first if statement.
Program will continue in the previous call juste after the for loop. And the last instruction puts a '.' char again in the empty cell... This is the instruction just after the for loop
...

Comment: Thank you. I added `break` and `board[xe][ye] = '.'` in the `for` loop and it works! There was no problem in calling by reference.

Comment: I got it. Your code is quite a nightmare. In the for loop, after the recursive call add if(isfull(board)) break; sorry for formatting, writing on phone...

Comment: Just seen you already solved it. Nice.